# How to create two or more NICs in two or more VMs with Azure to terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm working on how to stick two or more NICs to two or more VMSs using the for_each syntax. My code is as below.

var.tf

```
variable "vm_template" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    vm1 = {
      vm_name         = "vm-test"
      hostname        = "vm-test""
      os_publisher    = "erockyenterprisesoftwarefoundationinc1653071250513"
      os_offer        = "rockylinux"
      os_sku          = "free"
      os_version      = "8.6.0"
      osdisk_type     = "StandardSSD_LRS"
      osdisk_size     = "128"
      vm_type         = "Standard_D4s_v5"
      os_disk         = "osdisk01"
    }
  }
}

variable "nic_tempalte" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    nic1 = {
      nic_name = "nic01"
      enable_accelerated_networking = "true"
    }
    nic2 = {
      nic_name = "nic02"
      enable_accelerated_networking = "true"
    }
  }
}

variable "ip_configuration" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    ipconf1 = {
      ipconfig_name = "internal"
      ipconfig_primary = "true"
      ipconfig_private_ip_type = "Dynamic"
      ipconfig_private_ip = ""
    }
    ipconf2 = {
      ipconfig_name = "external"
      ipconfig_primary = "false"
      ipconfig_private_ip_type = "Dynamic"
      ipconfig_private_ip = ""
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each                      = var.nic_tempalte
  name                          = "${each.value.nic}"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  enable_accelerated_networking = "${each.value.enable_accelerated_networking}"
  
  dynamic ip_configuration {
    for_each = var.ip_configuration
    content {
    name                          = ip_configuration.value["ipconfig_name"]
    primary                       = ip_configuration.value["ipconfig_primary"]
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.network_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = ip_configuration.value["ipconfig_private_ip_type"]
    private_ip_address            = ip_configuration.value["ipconfig_private_ip"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = var.vm_template
...(omission)

  network_interface_ids = [
     { for k, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic : k => nic.id }
  ]

...(omission)
}
```

If you plan the above code, you will get the following error.

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on vm.tf line 81, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm":
│   81:   network_interface_ids = [
│   82:     { for k, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic : k => nic.id }
│   83:   ]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nic is object with 2 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string requi
```

I think the word object with 2 attributes is the key. Because you need to create more than one nic. I think we should use the nested for_each of var.template and var.nic_template. Isn't there a simpler way? If anyone could leave any answers, it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: If you are interested in fixing the error in your config in addition to the question, then note that both the message and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#network_interface_ids agree that the value needs to be type `list(string)` and not `list(map)`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to create nics.

I Created two Vms with 1Nic each:

Nics are list of strings in this case:

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "nics" {
  type = list(object({
    name             = string
    location         = string
    resource_group   = string
    subnet_id        = string
    private_ip_address_allocation      = string
    //nic_tags         = map(string)
  }))

  default = [
    {
      name  = "vm1-nic1"
         subnet_id        = "/subscriptions/8xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/example-network/subnets/subnet1"
          private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"      
      location       = "eastus"
      resource_group = "my-resource-group"
 
    },
    {
       name  = "vm2-nic"
           subnet_id        = "/subscriptions/8ae0844f-6525-411f-8df8-7a7e012aaa16/resourceGroups/v-sakavya-Mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/example-network/subnets/subnet2"
          private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
      location       = "eastus"
      resource_group = "my-resource-group"
    
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
variable "vms" {
  type = map(object({
    nic_name         = string
    vm_name          = string
    subnet_id        = string
    location         = string
    resource_group   = string
    vm_size          = string
    image_publisher  = string
    image_offer      = string
    image_sku        = string
    admin_username   = string
   // ssh_key          = string
  }))

  default = {
    "vm1" = {
      nic_name         = "vm1-nic"
      vm_name          = "vm1"
      subnet_id        = "/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/example-network/subnets/subnet1"
      location         = "eastus"
      resource_group   = "v-sakavya-Mindtree"
      vm_size          = "Standard_F2"
      image_publisher  = "Canonical"
      image_offer   = "UbuntuServer"
  image_sku        = "18.04-LTS"
  admin_username   = "ubuntu"
  admin_password = "Vm1Passw0rd@123!"
},
"vm2" = {
  nic_name         = "vm2-nic"
  vm_name          = "vm2"
  subnet_id        = "/subscriptions/x/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/example-network/subnets/subnet2"
  location         = "eastus"
  resource_group   = "v-sakavya-Mindtree"
  vm_size          = "Standard_F2"
  image_publisher  = "Canonical"
  image_offer      = "UbuntuServer"
  image_sku        = "18.04-LTS"
  admin_username   = "ubuntu"
  admin_password = "Vm2Passw0rd@123!"
}

  }
}
```

Main.tf:

nic creation:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  for_each = var.vms

  name                = each.value.nic_name
   location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value.nic_name}-ip-config"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  for_each = var.vms

  name                = each.value.vm_name
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  size                = each.value.vm_size
   admin_username      =  "axxer" 
  admin_password       =   "Pxxx12!"  
  disable_password_authentication = false

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example[each.key].id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    name              = "${each.value.vm_name}-os-disk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = each.value.image_publisher
    offer     = each.value.image_offer
    sku       = each.value.image_sku
    version   = "latest"
  }

  

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Multiple VMs and Nics can be created this way where multiple NIICS can be created to each VM:

**Note :** make sure the storage os disk doesn't get override:
Also make sure to mention primary NIC

variable.tf:

```
variable "vm_count" {
  type = number
  default = 2
}

variable "nic_count_per_vm" {
  type = number
  default = 2
}
```

main.tf:

```
# Create virtual network

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "myvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Create subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  count               = var.vm_count * var.nic_count_per_vm
  name                = "mysubnet${count.index}"
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes    = ["10.0.${count.index + 1}.0/24"]
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  count               = var.vm_count * var.nic_count_per_vm
  name                = "publicip${count.index}"
 resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

# Create network interfaces
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count                = var.vm_count * var.nic_count_per_vm
  name                 = "nic${count.index}"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig${count.index}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[count.index].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[count.index].id
  }
}

# Create virtual machines

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "vm${count.index}"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  vm_size             = "Standard_F2"

  storage_os_disk {
    //name              = "vmosdisk-{var.vmnames}"
    //caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
   //managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${count.index}-vm"
    admin_username = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "P@ssw0rd1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index * var.nic_count_per_vm ].id,
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[(count.index * var.nic_count_per_vm ) + 1].id
  ]

 primary_network_interface_id = azurerm_network_interface.nic[(count.index * var.nic_count_per_vm )].id

  # depends_on = [
  #   azurerm_network_interface.nic,
  #   azurerm_subnet.subnet,
  #   azurerm_public_ip.public_ip
  # ]
}
```

[image]

From [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#network_interface_ids)

> network_interface_ids is A list of Network Interface IDs which should
> be attached to this Virtual Machine. The first Network Interface ID in
> this list will be the Primary Network Interface on the Virtual
> Machine.

Comment: I want to attach multiple NICs to one VM. Also, preferably, I don't want to use the count.